# How to use Fuel library to pass an xml and get json response in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Example of an xml I am looking to pass:

```
  <osm-script output="json">
  <query into="_" type="node">
  <has-kv k="amenity" modv="" v="toilets"/>
  <around from="_" into="_" 
        lat="52.51633" lon="13.37751" radius="1000"/>
  </query>
  <print e="" from="_" geometry="skeleton"
         limit="" mode="body" n="" order="id" s="" w=""/>    
 </osm-script>'
```